# Build .NET project dependency by condition

Tags: .net, msbuild, dependency-management

I have one main project and several dependecies in my solution. I want my main project has only one reference to dependent project by condition (compilation symbol).

I tryed to add this code to project file for each dependend project:

```
<ItemGroup Condition="$(DefineConstants.Contains('SomeConstant'))">
  <ProjectReference Include="..\DependentProj1\DependentProj1.csproj">
    <Project>{7d971fa6-9225-4d54-b21c-077eb46c5dd4}</Project>
    <Name>DependentProj1</Name>
  </ProjectReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

In this case all dependend projects are built and only one binary file is copied to main output. It doesn't suit me.

I also tryed:

```
<Choose>
  <When Condition="$(DefineConstants.Contains('SomeConstant'))">
    ...
  </When>
</Choose>
```

But for some reasons it didn't work as I want.

Can anybody advise me how to build ONLY ONE dependency when I change conditional compilation symbol?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Consider using something like this

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <SomeConstantProp>...</SomeConstantProp>
   <DeclareConstants Condition="'$(SomeConstantProp)' != ''">
```

$(DeclareConstants);yourConst

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(SomeConstantProp)' != ''">
  <ProjectReference Include="..\DependentProj1\DependentProj1.csproj">
    <Project>{7d971fa6-9225-4d54-b21c-077eb46c5dd4}</Project>
    <Name>DependentProj1</Name>
  </ProjectReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Could you explain this please `<SomeConstantProp>...</SomeConstantProp>`

Comment: @AndrewVorobyov that is just creating a property - name it as you wish

Comment: And what about content of this tag?

Comment: what ever you want it to be as well @AndrewVorobyov - the conditions just look for it not to be empty

Comment: I did'n get it. How can I bind conditional compilation symbol to this tag? Earlier I received it from `$(DefineConstants)` but I can't insert this into tag content, right?

Comment: @AndrewVorobyov i dont understand

Comment: `$(DefineConstants)` it is property stored constant from build properties of project. Now I see that this way looks like mine, but property I used is already defined. But thank you!